# Local parameters in MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

If I have a controller like this...

`Public Function GetData(fromDate As Date, toDate As Date) As ActionResult`

then my url has to be english (MM-DD-YYYY) like ...

**.../GetData?fromDate=2-27-2014&toDate=9-29-2014**

But since all my users are danish (DD-MM-YYYY), this will not work...

**.../GetData?fromDate=27-2-2014&toDate=29-2-2014**

Can I tell MVC to expect danish (DD-MM-YYYY) arguments or do I have to translate the date to MM-DD-YYYY on the client before sending it to the server?

Comment: Post the date as string and normalize on the server before using the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC model binding takes into account Current Culture (locale). For example, your users are using `da-DK` culture and your application (server) is set to `en-US` culture. So obviously the date formats would be different between the two cultures.

One easy option for this is in your `Web.config` under `<system.web>` set

```
    <globalization culture="da-DK" uiCulture="da-DK" />
```

This globally configures your application to use `da-DK` culture. This way your controller action knows to expect the dates in `dd-MM-yyyy` format.

Scott Hanselman has a nice article on this topic: [Globalization, Internationalization and Localization ...](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx)

**UPDATE**

This answer is only valid for the POSTed data, however in MVC the query string is parsed using [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The `InvariantCulture`'s `ShortDatePattern` is `MM/dd/yyyy`.

For example, the following query string parameters would all parse as January 7, 2014: `01/07/2014`, `01-07-2014`, `01.07.2014`.

Also, the following would also parse as January 7, 2014: `2014/01/07`, `2014-01-07`, `2014.01.07`.

This last example aligns with the ISO international date format and this format should be used for query string parameters.

Comment: Good one - didn't know that one. That might solve lotta issues for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format, then your bindings will work for any locale.

In VB.Net you can use the string format `.ToString("s")` to create the parameters for your URL.

In JavaScript you can use the `.toISOString()` function to create the parameters for your URL.

The ISO 8601 date format will bind to a DateTimeOffset parameter in your controller:

```
Public Function GetData(fromDate As DateTimeOffset, toDate As DateTimeOffset) As ActionResult
```

Comment: I wish I could set both answers as correct - because both answers are VERY helpful - thanks for helping me out here!!!! :)